# Mac mini stops blinking in standby

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini

I'm on Macmini6,2 with current firmware and 10.8.4. When I send it to sleep it starts its on and off fading status LED thing to indicate it is now asleep.

When I come back a few hours later, it is dark, but the computer is still asleep and enters wake mode when I touch any key.

What's wrong there? Isn't the indicator LED supposed to blink all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is only with the most recent model, but apparently by default it is set to go into deep sleep after a few hours, and this turns the power light off entirely.

[This thread](http://www.avforums.com/forums/apple-mac/1696748-new-mac-mini-going-into-deep-sleep.html) on AVForums provides a command that should disable deep sleep, if that is what you want.

```
pmset -g
sudo pmset -a autopoweroff 0
```

After entering this it will prompt you for your password.